# pass an arraylist into SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the below code:

```
    ArrayList NumList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra ("name");
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (FirstName VARCHAR);");

        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values (NumList);");
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the NumList into the table. The above code shows an error saying "no such column: NumList)" How would I pass this information through?

Comment: sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " (FirstName VARCHAR);"); You have only one column in your table which is FirstName. Try to add NumList too.

Comment: I want the NumList to be stores in the FirstName column.

Comment: sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values (" + NumList[i] + ");");  You have to take NumList variable out.

Comment: I get the error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(String str: NumList){
sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " ( FirstName ) Values ('"+str+"');");
}
```

Comment: thanks that works, sorry to be a pain but any idea how I could retain the state of checkboxes after the app closes?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences to save the states.

Comment: how would I do this? I have tried but I can't seem to get it working

Comment: You save the states as boolean. If checked you save as true, if unchecked you save false. On launching the application you read them. if true you check if false you uncheck.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " ( FirstName ) Values ('"+NumList+"');");
```

Comment: thank you, that works :) is there anyway to display it as a list again or maybe automatically add a row for each value in the list?

Comment: my question is not fully answered, I would like to show the information as a list or add a new row for each value in the list

Comment: u have to put arraylist NumList in for loop

Comment: i answered again to ur question check my new answer